# Optmizing disk writes for Java Logger

Tags: java, optimization, io, logging

I am using Java.util.Logger to log various events of my project. I  am using a file handler to create the log. I see that the rate at which events are written to the log ( in the disk ) is almost the pace at which events are happening. This seems to be good and bad at same time. Good as event updates are written quickly, but I am concerned about the IO time. Sometimes there is a lot of data that needs to be written to the logs. So in those cases, my program would run slower because of this logging, which is not desirable.

It would be of great help, if somebody could suggest what I should do in this case. I do not care the rate at which events are logged, they just need to be there in the log file at the end of execution.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you have any buffering in memory of log events you risk loosing those if your application crashes.  Usually it is exactly those you want to know what said.

Answer (score 2):

A performance loss of 5-10% is expected when running full debug logging. This seems to be acceptable for our customers.

If the code to generate some of the content to log out is expensive, consider using a simple test like this to avoid executing this code when debug is turned off:

```
if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
  // code to generate the log entry
}
```

You can also create a `java.util.logging.MemoryHandler` and push out to a file in a regular interval.

Comment: Thanks Jochen, MemoryHandler should be fine for my application. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Jochen Bedersdorfer's answer is a good one and [just4log](http://just4log.sourceforge.net/) is a system that will do it automatically for you - via post-processing.  Therefore you won't have to ugly up your code with if statements around the log statements.

Answer (score 1):

Pexus has recently released an open source performance logging package - PerfLog,  that also includes an application logger based on java.util.logging.* API. It includes an option for asynchronous logging using Common J Work Manager that is availble in all J2EE container (1.4+)
For more information see: http://www.pexus.com/perflog

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try out another logging solution, like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) which is widely used (often in combination with commons-logging). It offers a performant approach to logging.

If you however desire even more control you can implement your own appender. Assuming you desire a file appender you can override the [append](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html#append%28org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent%29) routine of the [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html).

E.g.,

```
public class BatchingFileAppender extends FileAppender {
   private List<LoggingEvent> batch = new LinkedList<LoggingEvent>;
   public static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;


   @Override
   protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
       batch.add(event);

       // you can even optionally push ever 10'th or so messages to file
       if (batch.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
           appendBatch();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void reset() {
       appendBatch();
   }

   @Override
   protected void closeWriter() {
       appendBatch();
   } 

   private void appendBatch() {
       for(LoggingEvent event : batch) {
           super.append(event);
       }
       batch.clear();
   }

}
```

Comment: what is the benefit to rolling your own buffer like this rather than using the builtin `AsyncAppender`?

Comment: With this approach all logging events can be performed on application shutdown (with some minor modifications to the code above).

Answer (score 0):

Use a more-modern logging library such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) or [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) which have support for asynchronous/buffered appenders.

In log4j, you can use [AsyncAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) (which provides the buffering facility) and wire up a FileAppender to it:

> The AsyncAppender will collect the events sent to it and then dispatch them to all the appenders that are attached to it. You can attach multiple appenders to an AsyncAppender.
>
> The AsyncAppender uses a separate thread to serve the events in its buffer.

This way the events are written to the disk in a controlled manner, and your threads doing actual work are not tied up with disk I/O.

Or as a simpler option, consider if you really need to have the full output of the logs when running this program. It's often overkill to run an application in production with logging at the DEBUG level.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html). Same authors as log4j if I'm not mistaken.

> Based on our previous work on log4j, logback internals have been
>   re-written to perform about ten times faster on certain critical
>   execution paths. Not only are logback components faster, they have a
>   smaller memory footprint as well.